Mount Bitlocker Drive Using FVEK
Anyone know of a way to mount a Bitlocker drive in Windows using the FVEK pulled from a memory dump? I know it can be done with Dislocker in Linux, but I’d like a quick way to do it on the Windows side. To the best of my knowledge, manage-bde will only mount with a Recovery Key or password.
I also know Passware can use the FVEK to decrypt the drive and provide the VMK and Recovery Key, but it takes much too long (hours or even a day) for what is supposed to be “instant unlock”.
Edit to please the bot: is there any way to mount a Bitlocker drive in Windows using the FVEK parsed out of a memory dump?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
